# is it possible to send toast info to UI in background service in flutter

Tags: flutter

In flutter UI we could use this code to show some toast to user:

```
 onPressed: () {
      toast('success!');
 }),
```

when I run code in background service, the background service code look like this:

```
/// The entry of dart background service
/// NOTE: this method will be invoked by native (Android/iOS)
/// avoid Tree Shaking
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void playerBackgroundService() {
  CommonUtils.initialApp(ConfigType.PRO).whenComplete(() => {
     //do something
  });
}
```

is it possibe to send message to the UI toast and show to the user? how to send a message to the current UI toast? when I use toast in the background code, shows error like this:

```
Global OverlaySupport Not Initialized ! 
ensure your app wrapped widget OverlaySupport.global
```

if I want to notify the background code execute result, what should I  do make this possible?

Comment: its possible but you need to write native code for specific platform.